# Retrofit, call.enqueue

Tags: android-studio, retrofit, call

Here is my code:

```
retrofit2.Call<User> call = MainActivity.apiInterface.performUserLogin (username,password);
       Log.d(TAG,"retrofit");
        call.enqueue (new Callback<User> () {
            @Override
            public void onResponse( retrofit2.Call<User> call, Response<User> response )
            {
                Log.d (TAG,"in");
              if(response.body ().getResponse ().equals ("ok"))
                {
                    Log.d (TAG,"ok");
                    MainActivity.prefConfig.writeLoginStatus (true);
                    loginFormActivityLisener.performLogin (response.body ().getName ());
                }
                else if(response.body ().getResponse ().equals ("failed"))
              {
                  MainActivity.prefConfig.displayToast ("Login Failed... Please try again...");
                  Log.d(TAG,"failed");
              }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure( retrofit2.Call<User> call, Throwable t ) {

            }
        });
```

I have question, why call.enqueue is not working? It is like it wasnt there. Its do nothing.

Comment: have you tried checking the `logcat`/ `adding breakpoints`

Comment: Yes and it skip over

Comment: try adding a log statement in `onFailure` and check if its getting called

Comment: still do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enqueue() function of Retrofit works asynchronously. It is a background task and runs the request on a background thread. If you debug your code, you will most probably see debugger skips the enqueue call and continues to execute next line. When background thread finishes, after skipping a few more lines maybe, it gets back to call.enqueue().

If you want to use a foreground task, you can choose execute() function, or there are other implementations to wait main thread until callback responses, like using events (see EventBus library).